# How can I fix binary file corrupted by pseudo-terminal option during ssh transfer?

Tags: postgresql, docker, ssh

I had create the dump of database which located inside docker container using this command:

```
docker exec -it container_id pg_dump -U postgres -Fc -d database_name > local_file.dump
```

> -t flag enable pseudo-terminal mode. As a result local_file.dump is corrupted.

Can I fix this binary file?

Answer (score 0):

Transfer the file once again without the `-t` switch. There are more things that could go wrong and you can't know if the characters were inserted by the `TTY` or they belong there.

You might be lucky with finding tabs, spaces and terminal control characters. You can also try to manually understand the binary postgres format and try to fix the problems, but there is no general advice.

Do it once more.